# Can one perl6 module conditionally 'use' another perl6 module?

Tags: raku

Is there a sensible way to have one perl6 module check for the presence of another perl6 module and to 'use' it if and only if it is installed?

Something like this...

```
module Polygons;

if $available {
    use Measure;                #only if Measure is installed
}

class Rectangle is export {
    has $.width;
    has $.height;

    method area {
        $!width * $!height;     #provides operator overload for Measure * Measure
    }
}
#====================

module Measure;

class Measure is export {
    has $.value;
    has $.unit;

    method Real {
        $!value;
    }
    method Str {
        "$!value $!unit";
    }
    method multiply( $argument ) {
        my $result = $.;
        $result.value = $!value * $argument;
        $result.unit  = "$!unit2";
        return $result;
    }
}

multi infix:<*> ( Measure:D $left, Measure:D $right ) is export {
    return $result.multiply( $argument );
}

#====================

#main.p6

use Polygons;
use Measure;

my $x = Measure.new( value => 10, unit => 'm' );
my $y = Measure.new( value => 20, unit => 'm' );

my $rect = Rectangle.new( width => $x, height => y );
say $rect.area;        #'200 m2'
```

The idea is to propagate the operator overload (infix:<*> in this case) back up the class inheritance so that one store more elaborate objects in the attributes.

(Without tearing up the drains please - since I suspect there is always a way!)

Answer (score 4):

So the first version of this answer was essentially useless.

Here's the first new thing I've come up with that works with what I understand your problem to be. I haven't tried it on the repo yet.

In a file `a-module.pm6`:

```
unit module a-module;
our sub infix:<*> ($l,$r) { $l + $r } }
```

The `our` means we'll be able to see this routine if we can `require` it, though it'll only be visible via its fully qualified name `&a-module::infix:<*>`.

Then in a using file:

```
use lib '.';
try require a-module;
my &infix:<*> = &a-module::infix:<*> // &OUTER::infix:<*>;
say 1 * 2 # 2 or 3 depending on whether `a-module.pm6` is found
```

The default routine used if the module is missing can be the one from `OUTER` (as shown) or from `CALLER` or whatever other [pseudo package](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages) you prefer.

This problem/solution seems so basic I suspect it must be on SO or in the doc somewhere. I'll publish what I've got then explore more tomorrow.

Comment: So, I have had a chance to test this and found that it doesn't work. After reading the doc on require and a little prototyping I found that @raiph you were very close, but ... (i) to import the symbol it must be explicitly defined at Compile time with this ... `try require Measure qw{&infix:<*>};` which works if the module is present... (ii) however, when I remove the module file, as expected the require fails, but then I get the error `Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Uninstantiable; Callable)` so the unloaded placeholder prevents vanilla use of infix:<*>.

Comment: Is there a way to test for the presence of the module file, and only if present to define the symbols for compile time?

Comment: no cigar... `
my &infix:<*> := &MeasureModule::infix:<*> if try require MeasureModule;
#->Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Null; VMNull) `

Comment: appreciate your patience.

Comment: hi @raiph (and anyone else) - I have put the basic prototype in git - you can go `git clone https://github.com/p6steve/perl6-Slang-Dict-proto.git` and have a play yourself if you like...