# Should I get a raku Segfault depending on order of use statements?

Tags: raku

I am seeking help to prevent me tearing my hair out. I have a couple of interdependent modules:

- Physics::Unit
- Physics::Measure (which uses Physics::Unit)

Now I have created a new module Physics::UnitAffix whose job is to export combinations of SI prefixes and SI units as raku postfix operators (cm, mm, nm and so on) into the script namespace.

Here's a golfed version of the new module:

```
unit module Physics::UnitAffixQ:ver<0.0.4>:auth<Steve Roe (p6steve@furnival.net)>;

{
use Physics::Unit;

Unit.new( factor => 0.000000001, offset => 0, defn => 'nanometre', type => '', 
      dims => [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], dmix => ("metre"=>1).MixHash, 
      names => ['nm'], stock => True );

}

sub do-postfix( Real $v, Str $n, Str $t ) { 
    my $pmt = "Physics::Measure::$t";
    return ::($pmt).new(value => $v, units => $n);
} 

sub postfix:<nm> (Real:D $x) is export(:DEFAULT) { do-postfix($x,'nm','Length') }
```

And here's the raku script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku 
use lib '../lib';
use Physics::UnitAffixQ;   #must be 1st 
use Physics::Measure;

my $l = 1nm;                say ~$l;   #1 nm
```

I would like users of the modules to be able to write their use statements in any order. However, if they use Physics::Measure first, I either get a SegFault. Or slightly better I have been able to pin down to this error:

```
No such symbol 'Physics::Measure::Length'
  in sub do-postfix at /Users/stephenroe/Dropbox/ThreeMeasures/raku-Physics-Measure/bin/../lib/Physics/UnitAffixQ.rakumod (Physics::UnitAffixQ) line 14
  in sub postfix:<nm> at /Users/stephenroe/Dropbox/ThreeMeasures/raku-Physics-Measure/bin/../lib/Physics/UnitAffixQ.rakumod (Physics::UnitAffixQ) line 17
  in block <unit> at synopsis-unitaffixq.raku line 6
```

Can anyone advise on (i) whether I should have to specify the order of use statements and/or (ii) how I can fix this error?

Also to mention this previous [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064251/can-one-perl6-module-conditionally-use-another-perl6-module) and note already tried the application of use within curls to limit the scope.

My kit: Welcome to ™ v2020.10. Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d. Built on MoarVM version 2020.10.

I have created a new branch 'SO64837072' of raku-Physics-Measure on GitHub to help Reproduce this setup, please go:

```
    zef install Physics::Unit
 or zef install https://github.com/p6steve/raku-Physics-Unit.git
    git clone git clone https://github.com/p6steve/raku-Physics-Measure.git
    git checkout SO64837072
    cd raku-Physics-Measure/bin
    ./synopsis-unitaffixq.raku
```

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a segfault at all — but depending on what's going on in each module, you may need to order them in a particular way.  I can't take a look at it right htis second, but if someone else doesn't see it right off the bat, I'll look into it in the next day or so for yo

Comment: Is `NativeCall` involved in any of the modules?  If yes, then look at that first.  If not, then most definitely this is a bug that needs looking into and making an issue for it would be best.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen - no NativeCall involved...

Comment: hi @raiph - I have just edited my original post to help folk Reproduce the problem - please see instructions above

Comment: @p6steve Thanks. :) I still can't myself verify it's reproducible (system problems), but your instructions look spot on, and in good time for the attention which will hopefully be brought by the next rakunews.

Comment: hi @lizmat - I have raised issue https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4038